# Dual Israeli - American citizen. Which countries can a normal American enter, that I cannot as an American and Israeli?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, dual-nationality, israeli-citizens

As per wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_passport#Countries_that_do_not_accept_Israeli_passports

> six countries — Iran, Kuwait, Lebanon, Libya, Syria and Yemen — do not allow entry to non-Israelis with evidence of travel to Israel, or whose passports have a used or unused Israeli visa.

Am I to understand that the other 22 countries will be okay if I enter with my US passport? I obviously won't wave around my Israeli passport in front of their capital, or anything else provocative. But should I fear that the border control agents will ask if I have any connection to Israel, and when I truthfully say that I am an Israeli citizen, that they will deport me?

My US passport doesn't have any entry or exit stamps from Israel, because Israel no longer does that, and I only entered / exited with my Israeli passport. However, I was born in Jerusalem Israel, so my US passport does say that I was born in Jerusalem (but it doesn't write Israel).

Comment: Were you born in Israel?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that. I was born in Jerusalem, so it doesn't explicitly write Israel, rather just Jerusalem. Does that count? (I'll edit my post with that)

Comment: I've been to Lebanon a few times, and in my experience they do not ask you if you've been to Israel. In fact, they never asked me anything. They did leaf through my passport though, and were interested in my entry stamps for Jordan.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I'm pretty sure most border officials would know that Jerusalem is in Israel, so the fact that "Israel" is not explicitly written in your passport likely won't matter much.

Comment: @EM0 Well, Wikipedia knows a handful of places in the US called Jerusalem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_(disambiguation) ,so there are lots of US citizens who are born in Jerusalem without having anything to do with Israel. Of course, pretending that this is the case for OP would be lying.

Comment: Are you asking about personal safety? Being allowed to enter? Legal exposure in Israel ?

Answer (score 3):

As an American citizen you have the same rights as any other American. A lot of non-Israeli US citizens are born in Jerusalem, so this on its own is not an evidence of being an Israeli.

That said, if asked and you lie you may be refused entry because you lied. Israeli population registry has leaked online multiple times, so they may be able to cross reference if they want.

In addition as an Israeli you're forbidden from traveling to certain countries where you could go as an American (Iran or Syria for example). It doesn't matter which passport you use, as a citizen you're always under the Israeli jurisdiction and may be prosecuted.

Israelis have been traveling to Muslim countries using their dual citizenships since forever, you won't be the first. But it is a risk for personal safety even if officials don't treat you any differently than any other American. You would be under the US protection, of course, diplomatically, but those who seek to harm Israelis wouldn't care much.